# Why is my stack overflowing when I push less data through it?

Tags: java, recursion, graphics, paint

I am working on creating a weighted US map and I have broken the zip codes down into 3 digit zip zones. I then use a for loop that iterates 1000 times to color each 3 digit zip zone a random color.

This works every time with out issue. My current issue is coming in if I start my for loop count above 310. Anything less than 310 and it loops through perfectly. So since raising the initial count would mean that it would run the recursive code less, then this does make any sense to me.

The code that calls the for loop:

```
private void GUI()
{       
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new MigLayout());

    try
    {
        mapImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Res/Zipzone map of the US.png"));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g = mapImg.createGraphics();

    for(int i = 311; i < 1001; i++)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String count = "";
        int red = rand.nextInt(220) + 25;
        int green = rand.nextInt(220) + 25;
        int blue = rand.nextInt(220) + 25;
        if(i < 100)
        {
            count = "0" + i;
        }
        else
        {
            count = i + "";
        }
        if(i <= 512)
        {
            ApplyColor(count, new Color(red, blue, green));
        }
        else if( i > 909)
        {
            ApplyColor3(count, new Color(red, blue, green));
        }
        else
        {
            ApplyColor2(count, new Color(red, blue, green));
        }
    }

    frame.add(new JLabel("", new ImageIcon(GetScaledImage(new ImageIcon(mapImg).getImage(), 1400, 875)), JLabel.CENTER), "GROW, PUSH");
    frame.setTitle("US Map");
    frame.setSize(1500,900);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Small example of the apply color function:

```
private void ApplyColor(String zip, Color color)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    if(zip.equals("010"))
    {
        try
        {
            x = 3339;
            y = 672;
            FloodFill(x, y, new Color(mapImg.getRGB(x, y)), color);
            x = 3361;
            y = 681;
            FloodFill(x, y, new Color(mapImg.getRGB(x, y)), color);
        }
        catch(AWTException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the FloodFill function:

```
public void FloodFill(int x, int y, Color targetColor, Color replacementColor) throws AWTException
{
    if(new Color(mapImg.getRGB(x, y)).equals(replacementColor))
    {
        return;
    }

    g.setColor(replacementColor);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);

    if(new Color(mapImg.getRGB(x-1, y)).equals(targetColor))
    {
        FloodFill(x-1, y, targetColor, replacementColor);
    }

    if(new Color(mapImg.getRGB(x+1, y)).equals(targetColor))
    {
        FloodFill(x+1, y, targetColor, replacementColor);
    }

    if(new Color(mapImg.getRGB(x, y-1)).equals(targetColor))
    {
        FloodFill(x, y-1, targetColor, replacementColor);
    }

    if(new Color(mapImg.getRGB(x, y+1)).equals(targetColor))
    {
        FloodFill(x, y+1, targetColor, replacementColor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know why you receive this error when you start from 310 or more, because the part of your code that deals with what you are referring to as "zip codes" is too bizarre to try and make sense of, and because in any case, making sense out of that would not benefit any other visitors of the site, only you.

What I suspect is happening is that by starting at 310 or above the arrangement of zip codes is such that your recursive flood-fill algorithm is required to do more painting than if you did not.

Which brings us to your recursive flood-fill algorithm.

That's not the right way to do flood-fill.

It might be considered right in the academia, but not in the real world.

If your algorithm is given a long stretch of pixels to paint, it will recurse for every single one of them.  In your initialization code I see you setting the width of your frame to 1500, and elsewhere I see you using coordinates in excess of 3000, which means that you do in fact give your algorithm long stretches of pixels to paint.  Which means that it recurses a lot.  That's why you get a stack overflow exception.

To correct your problem, you need to rewrite your recursive flood-fill algorithm so that it does not recurse so much.  For example, instead of recursing each time you visit a pixel to the left, have it loop to the left for as long as there are pixels to paint, and only recurse for the pixel above and the pixel below each painted pixel.  The same holds for visiting pixels to the right.  That's an easy way to reduce the recursion depth of your algorithm by orders of magnitude.

It also has the benefit of performing much better, because once you know all the pixels that you need to paint in a row, you can paint them all with a single drawing call, instead of performing one `fillRect()` per pixel.  We are talking about orders of magnitude better performance here.

If that is not enough to solve your stack overflow problems, then you might want to consider replacing your algorithm with one which uses a stack data structure instead of actually invoking itself.  Conversion of a recursive algorithm to a non-recursive that uses a stack data structure is something that you can look up and find plenty of solutions to.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: I don't see you performing any checks anywhere to see whether your x or y has exceeded the dimensions of your image. I hope you have some trick in place to handle that, i.e. a border painted around the edge of your image which will never be equal to the `targetColor`.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed advice. I did some more research on flood filling and was able to come up with a Queue system that works out much better for me.